# Using Tempdata in a class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, tempdata

I made an annotation for pages that require logging in, if the user is not logged in it will be redirected to the login page. I would also like to add an error which requires tempdata to view the error. Otherwise i have to set an message and check if the user is logged in every controller.

So my question is if it's possible to set a tempdata in a non controller, if it's possible how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you made a action filter for those pages? If so, you can access tempdata in the filter context.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Controller.TempData
            ...
}
```